# docker run always fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, device-mapper

Every time that I try to run a container with docker I get the following error:

```
# docker run hello-world
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container e55ff9914b3a671d63158adce03379b8d2baef0f32f23c3b47344c6edddedc05: no such file or directory
```

I tried to get more information running the daemon in my console with debug enabled:

```
# docker -dD &
[1] 6307
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build                     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load
...
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=786b29d/1.7.1 execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=devicemapper version=1.7.1
# docker run hello-world
DEBU[0007] Calling POST /containers/create              
INFO[0007] POST /v1.19/containers/create                
DEBU[0007] [deviceset] AddDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init basehash=975b84d108f1024953937167506c2935a081c8c55ae9e9f7b7deee118605367f) 
DEBU[0007] registerDevice(16, 08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [deviceset] AddDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init basehash=975b84d108f1024953937167506c2935a081c8c55ae9e9f7b7deee118605367f) END 
DEBU[0007] activateDeviceIfNeeded(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [deviceset] AddDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc basehash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] registerDevice(17, 08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [deviceset] AddDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc basehash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) END 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] Unmount(/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] Unmount done                     
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] deactivateDevice(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] removeDevice START(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] removeDevice END(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] deactivateDevice END(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc-init) END 
DEBU[0007] activateDeviceIfNeeded(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] Unmount(/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] Unmount done                     
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] deactivateDevice(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] removeDevice START(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] removeDevice END(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] deactivateDevice END(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0007] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) END 
DEBU[0007] Calling POST /containers/{name:.*}/attach    
INFO[0007] POST /v1.19/containers/08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1 
DEBU[0007] attach: stdout: begin                        
DEBU[0007] attach: stderr: begin                        
DEBU[0007] Calling POST /containers/{name:.*}/start     
INFO[0007] POST /v1.19/containers/08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc/start 
DEBU[0007] activateDeviceIfNeeded(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
ERRO[0007] leaving endpoint failed: a container has already joined the endpoint 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] Unmount(/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] Unmount done                     
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] deactivateDevice(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] removeDevice START(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] removeDevice END(docker-253:5-918236-08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] deactivateDevice END(08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) 
DEBU[0008] [devmapper] UnmountDevice(hash=08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc) END 
ERRO[0008] Handler for POST /containers/{name:.*}/start returned error: Cannot start container 08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc: no such file or directory 
ERRO[0008] HTTP Error                                    err=Cannot start container 08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc: no such file or directory statusCode=404
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 08eedfc4de5340a55498a136a667a1ed73f1fae75cbb1fac8469e703926a19fc: no such file or directory
```

But I still cannot find a clue about the problem.

Is there anything that I can investigate to find out how to solve this?

EDIT:

Additional information:

```
# docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64                         
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
# docker ps -a        
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
08eedfc4de53        hello-world         "/hello"            43 minutes ago                                              serene_sammet
```

Comment: what version of docker are you running ? post output of `docker version` pls
Can you find it locally if you list your containers ? `docker ps -a`

Comment: @MarceloCerri Can you add the Image ID as well (e.g. the output of `docker images`)?